# How to write a Snowpark Python code (in Snowflake Snowsight) to PUT data into Netsuite using API / external network access method?

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions, netsuite-rest-api

I have a manufacturing firm's data in snowflake database which I need to update it into Netsuite on a daily basis. There are multiple tables that need to be loaded and updated into the Netsuite on a regular basis using the PUT method.
The tables have to be loaded for the first time into the Netsuite and then updated regularly using a function or automated task.

The requirement is to do this using Snowpark/Python in Snowsight (snowflake's web interface) and the external network access method. I have all the required credentials for the API connection and have gone through a few examples but I still very new to this and feeling a little overwhelmed with creating an automated function/task that would do this.

The resources I see online are mostly openai related and that works but I'm not able to get any examples on how to write one for PUT method.

It would be a big help if anyone can share any codes, tips or resources that might be more specific to my requirement.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.